# Python pandas - merge dataframes rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas to show  dataframe, and my df looks like so:

```
  Day     Hour     Name     Msg
sunday     10        a       b
sunday     11        a       b
sunday     11        a       b
monday     12        a       b
tuesday    10        a       b
tuesday    10        a       b
```

now I want to summarize it to look like so:

```
sunday  3
monday  1
tuesday 2
```

and put this data in a dataframe so I will be able to plot it.

any idea how can I do it? thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html)

```
print (df.groupby('Day').size())
Day
monday     1
sunday     3
tuesday    2
dtype: int64
```

and then if need plot [`bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.groupby('Day').size().plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

If order od days is important convert column `Day` to [ordered categorical](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#sorting-and-order):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cat = ['sunday','monday','tuesday']
df.Day = df.Day.astype('category', ordered=True, categories=cat)

df.groupby('Day').size().plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image: graph1]

If dont want use `categorical`, another solution is [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by `cat`:

```
cat = ['sunday','monday','tuesday']
df.groupby('Day').size().reindex(cat).plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you though I didn't understand the `"ordered categorical"` what is it exactly? I couldn't understand from the url you gave.

Comment: sorry, it was bad link. need http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#sorting-and-order

Comment: So after groupby you get first column called `index` from `days` and it is sorted alphanumeric. But if need custom sorting like by days of week, need create ordered categories - then it sorts by order of values in `list` `cat`

Answer (score 1):

[jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41115942/240490) is great, but there is a slightly easier way:

```py
df.Day.value_counts()
```

Yields:

```
sunday     3
tuesday    2
monday     1
Name: Day, dtype: int64
```

They are ordered largest to smallest groups, which helps things not get lost.
If you want them in a given order, reindex to the original order:

```
df.Day.value_counts().reindex(df.Day.unique())
```

Giving:

```
sunday     3
monday     1
tuesday    2
Name: Day, dtype: int64
```

You could also order them any way you like, giving a custom list to `.reindex()`.

For plotting, you can then do:

```
df.Day.value_counts().plot.bar()
```

[image]

Or

```
df.Day.value_counts().plot.bar(figsize=(2,2))
```

For:

[image]